# What is gstatic and why did it show up in my spreadsheet?

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, dropbox, malware

I'm running 14.04 LTS.  I have a LibreOfficeCalc spreadsheet that I save to Dropbox.  Today when I opened the sheet, near the last row containing data is a vertically oriented web address, in red text, over top both data and empty cells.  The web address begins with "https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icon/mail/images/cleardot/gif . . ."
I've placed the cursor in all of the cells but cannot find the cell this originates in.
I searched gstatic.com and have found that it is either owned and for the benefit of Google or other sites report it is a malicious virus.
What is it?  I'm already concerned.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fear not. `gstatic.com` is a domain owned and controlled by Google, Inc. They use the domain to host static content for their own services. I'm not sure how or why it ended up in your spreadsheet, but it's *probably* not malicious.

Comment: Thank you.  I should have added that the sheet is saved to Google Drive as well.  Perhaps that's how the link or watermark or ? came to be.

Comment: @user89064 - I think that's it. Myaybe in Google Spreadsheets some hidden cells are added. If my answer helped you, please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: @user89064 I see that you still haven't accepted my answer. I it helped you, which I hope I did, please accept my answer by following the instructions here http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers